# Unable to deploy EJB : AClassName from AJarFile.jar : null

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, ear

I have an ear application that I try to deploy on one of our weblogic server.

I get the following error :

```
    Unable to deploy EJB: SimpleTypeTablesManagementFacade from simpletypemgt.jar:

    null


at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:514)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:227)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$2.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:531)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:165)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:157)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteObject.onBind(ClusterableRemoteObject.java:189)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bindHere(BasicNamingNode.java:371)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.bindHere(ServerNamingNode.java:140)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bind(BasicNamingNode.java:317)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.bind(WLEventContextImpl.java:277)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EjbJndiService.bind(EjbJndiService.java:47)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EjbJndiService.replicatedBind(EjbJndiService.java:29)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.Ejb2JndiBinder.bindEJBObject(Ejb2JndiBinder.java:73)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.Ejb2JndiBinder.bindToJNDI(Ejb2JndiBinder.java:90)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.Ejb3SessionBinder.bindToJNDI(Ejb3SessionBinder.java:123)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.activate(ClientDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:1228)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.Ejb3SessionBeanInfoImpl.activate(Ejb3SessionBeanInfoImpl.java:513)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.activate(EJBDeployer.java:1320)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:493)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:227)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$2.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:531)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:165)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:157)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

The thing that I don't understant is that my ear works on another weblogic server with the exactly same config that the one that not working.

Comment: this is a weird answer, but this helped me as well. You can solve this by unzipping the jar and placing it manually in the directory. Restart the server after placing the files

Comment: are you getting the same error this time or some other error ?

Comment: Same error, I don't understand what could do this. I read that the cache may do this so I deleted it but it changed nothing